# How to convert a class A to class B?

Tags: java, class, type-conversion

I am working on a method where I've written the following line here:

```java
public class XeroTrackingCategoryClient extends TrackingCategoryTransformationClient {

    public List<ErpListEntry> getCustomFieldListDataByName(String entityCode, String customFieldListName, Boolean fullObject, DateTime lastSyncTime, Boolean isActive) {
        try {
            Optional<TrackingCategory> trackingCategory = trackingCategoryTransformationClient.getErpListDataById(entityCode, null, customFieldListName, null).stream().findFirst();
...cont.
```

As you can see from the `TrackingCategoryTransformationClient` class below, this yields an error as the abstract method `getErpListDataById` returns Optional`<AccountingObject>` and not Optional`<TrackingCategory>` which is what the variable is expecting.

I cannot change the class that is T is bounded by in the generic since other methods depend on it

Instead, I want to know if it's possible to convert the `AccountingObject` object to `TrackingCategory` instead?

`TrackingCategory` inherits (extends) from `AccountingObject` so I tried downcasting by `(TrackingCategory)` to the trackingCategoryTransformation class but this gave me an "Inconvertible types" error where AccountingObject cannot be cast to TrackingCategory

Thus, I'm trying to understand what I can do to convert the class to TrackingCategory.

**TrackingCategoryTransformationClient**

```java
public abstract class TrackingCategoryTransformationClient extends BaseTransformationClient {

    protected TrackingCategoryTransformationClient(AccountingPackageService accountingPackageService, IHttpHeaderFactory httpHeaderFactory, TransformationConnector transformationConnector, RestTemplate restTemplate) {
        super(accountingPackageService, httpHeaderFactory, transformationConnector, restTemplate);
    }

    public TrackingCategoryTransformationClient(SSLRestTemplate restTemplate, TransformationConnector transformationConnector, WhereClauseBuilderFactory whereClauseBuilderFactory, AccountingPackageService accountingPackageService, IHttpHeaderFactory httpHeaderFactory) {
        super(accountingPackageService, httpHeaderFactory, transformationConnector, restTemplate);
    }

    public abstract <T extends AccountingObject> List<T> getErpListDataById(String entityCode, AccountingObjectType accountingObjectType, String customFieldListName, List<CodeRef> filterList);
}
```

Comment: _Instead, I want to know if it's possible to convert the AccountingObject object to TrackingCategory instead?_ If TrackingCategory extends AccountingObject - this means all TrackingCategory objects are AccountingObject. But the reverse is not true i.e. not all AccountingObject are TrackingCategory.  That's the basic of inheritance.  And that's why you can't (up)cast a AccountingObject to TrackingCategory.  You need to put custom method which takes AccountingObject and crates a new instance of TrackingCategory (using it's constructor i.e. `return new TrackingCategory(<params required>)`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possible solutions (with `TrackingCategory extends AccountingObject`).
The first one is to cast to `TrackingCategory`.:

```
Optional<TrackingCategory> trackingCategory = trackingCategoryTransformationClient
    .getErpListDataById(entityCode, null, customFieldListName, null)
    .stream()
    .filter(TrackingCategory.class::isInstance)
    .map(TrackingCategory.class::cast)
    .findFirst();
```

You can also `filter` and `map` on `Optional` but it would be empty if not the first but the second entry is a `TrackingCategory`:

```
Optional<TrackingCategory> trackingCategory = trackingCategoryTransformationClient
    .getErpListDataById(entityCode, null, customFieldListName, null)
    .stream()
    .findFirst()
    .filter(TrackingCategory.class::isInstance)
    .map(TrackingCategory.class::cast);
```

The second solution is to give the compiler a hint of the generic `T` but you should be sure that all elements are `TrackingCategory`:

```
Optional<TrackingCategory> trackingCategory = trackingCategoryTransformationClient
    .<TrackingCategory> getErpListDataById(entityCode, null, customFieldListName, null)
    .stream()
    .findFirst();
```